# Retrieve semantic predicate and named entity tag from nltk boxer

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

How to get the semantic predicate and named entity tag after using the nltk boxer?

```
import nltk
x = nltk.sem.boxer.Boxer()
x.interpret("The quick brown fox jumped.")
```